# How to rename MySQL query result

Tags: mysql

How do I rename an output of a query? 
I have this query:

```
   select * 
   from (generalprofile left join applicant on applicant.profileID = 
   generalprofile.profileID) as A 
   inner join (generalprofile left join applicant on applicant.profileID = 
   generalprofile.profileID) as B on A.applicationID = B.applicationID ;
```

and I need to inner join the results of 2 queries.
"AS" doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You don't build the select tables in right way
inside the ( ) you must place a valid select  .. not only the table name and join

```
  select * 
   from ( select * form generalprofile 
          left join applicant on applicant.profileID = 
   generalprofile.profileID) A 
   inner join (select * from generalprofile 
          left join applicant on applicant.profileID = 
   generalprofile.profileID) B on A.applicationID = B.applicationID ;
```